# How to display individual cache data from React-Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-query

My application has a user input a `query`, then fetches the `response data` and is also `cached`.

For each `cache data`, I want to display a button for every `previous query` that users can click to again load that data on the screen.

Let's say I first input the id `1`, then the `data` is `cached` and rendered. When I log my `cached data` with `Object.values(cacheData.queriesMap)` I receive `{["rickandmorty",0]: Query, ["rickandmorty","1"]: Query}`. I now want to iterate through my cached data and display each individual query.

```
// <Home />
const cachedCharacters = Object.values(cacheData.queriesMap).map(character => (
    <button>{character.state.data.name}</button>
))

return (
    <div>
      {cachedCharacters}
    </div>
)
```

However, I receive a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. I suspect the reason for this error is because the first query is `["rickandmorty",0]`, a non-existing item that the application had fetched upon mounting.

[image: undefined from initial fetch]

I then set up my application to disable fetching upon component mount.

```
// <Home/>
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(
    ["rickandmorty", idQuery],
    handleRickAndMortyFetch,
    {
      enabled: false || idQuery !== 0,
  );
```

Yet, the application still makes the initial fetch upon mounting. If I first input the id `1`, I again receive `{["rickandmorty",0]: Query, ["rickandmorty","1"]: Query}`.

If the `initial fetch` is what's preventing each individual `cache data` to be rendered, how do I `disable` the `initial fetch` if `enabled: false` is not working? If it's a different issue preventing each individual cache data to be rendered, kindly suggest a solution. https://codesandbox.io/s/rick-and-morty-render-cache-data-8dv6y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. The initial query in the dev-tools you are seeing doesn't necessarily mean it is getting fetched. If you look through the state of the `idQuery` 0, there are no counts of it having its' data/error being updated. It's just in an **idle** state.

I suggest you try and filter your `cacheData.queriesMap` initially before mapping to make sure that your characters have data. You can either check the `state.data` or make sure the query has a `state.status === 'success'`. Or the easiest way might be to just show which queries already have data.

```
  const cachedCharacters = Object.values(
    cacheData.queriesMap
  ).map((character, index) => (
    <>
      {character.state.data ? (
        <button key={`${character.state.data.name}${index}`}>
          {character.state.data.name}
        </button>
      ) : null}
    </>
  ));
```

Comment: I now see that idQuery 0 is an idle state. Thank you for the clear solution! @Leomar-amiel